# How to add mjs javascript extension to Atom?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, config, atom-editor

I upgraded to node 8.5 and I'm using ES Modules... which require mjs... how do I add the mjs extension to the JavaScript syntax highlighter in Atom 1.20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: https://atom.io/packages/file-types

Source: http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#_customizing_language_recognition

```
config.cson

"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
        "source.js": [
          'mjs'
        ]
```